# jQuery datepicker not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, .net-1.1

Why is the following giving me an error in IE8?  It works fine in Chrome:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#txtDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "+0:+1",
            showButtonPanel: false,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../../images/Calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });

    });

</script>
```

So absolutely no issues with this in Chrome, but IE8 gives me the following error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/27.0.1453.110; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 12 Jun 2013 15:18:48 UTC

Message: 'length' is null or not an object
Line: 139
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://intranet/aspnet_client/system_web/1_1_4322/WebUIValidation.js
```

The datepicker still works though, it popsup when I click the icon, I can select a date and the date appears in the textbox.  But when I click the date, the datepicker is supposed to disappear, but it doesn't, instead it displays the above error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you happen to be using ASP..?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock, Yes, updated tags!

Comment: It seems like the problem is with ASP, not JS. Or rather, it seems the problem is in your WebUIValidation.js file from the error.

Comment: As stated by others ASP.Net client side validation is interfering, try to disable all validators when your page loads up and on submit button enable all of them and fire them to do client side validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently a bug in jQuery. I just added a do nothing event handler to "onSelect" event of the jQuery datepicker and it worked fine. Below is the modified jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "+0:+1",
        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../../images/Calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function () { }
    });

});
```

I was getting the error in IE 10 as well. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Also note that support for IE 6/7/8 was dropped in jQuery 2.x.